# Spring Data Neo4j and InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException for @Index property

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have added uuid property to my SDN 4 Base entity so now it looks like:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = true, primary = true)
    private String uuid;

...

}
```

Right now some of my tests stopped working.

I have a `Commentable` abstract class:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class Commentable extends BaseEntity {

    private final static String COMMENTED_ON = "COMMENTED_ON";

    @Relationship(type = COMMENTED_ON, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void addComment(Comment comment) {
        if (comment != null) {
            comments.add(comment);
        }
    }

    public void removeComment(Comment comment) {
        comments.remove(comment);
    }

}
```

Different `NodeEntity` from my domain model extend this class.. like

```
public class Decision extends Commentable
public class Product extends Commentable
```

etc

This my SDN 4 repository

```
@Repository
public interface CommentableRepository extends GraphRepository<Commentable> {
}
```

Right now when I try to access

```
commentableRepository.findOne(commentableId);
```

where commentableId is Decision id or Product id it is fails with a following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Supplied id does not match primary index type on supplied class.; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jException: Supplied id does not match primary index type on supplied class.
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SessionFactoryUtils.convertOgmAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.translateExceptionIfPossible(SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.findOne(Unknown Source)
```

But if I remove `@Index(unique = true, primary = true)` from my `BaseEntity.uuid` field everything starts working fine.

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong `Repository`. `GraphRepository` is a legacy implementation. The new implementation is called `Neo4jRepository`.

Try:

```
public interface CommentableRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Commentable, String> {

    ...
}
```

The key difference is the second parameterized type which is the type of the `ID` used for the domain class; in this case `String uuid`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed my repo to `CommentableRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Commentable, Long>`  not String.. because I still using Long(`@GraphId private Long id;`) as Id but the issue is not gone..

Comment: There is still confusion with the `@GraphId` stuff. `@GraphId` has nothing to do with `Repository`s. Change it to `String` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks digx1. I'm confused, isn't `@GraphId` the ID used for the domain class? In my case, I don't have a uuid. Why should i set `<Commentable, String>` instead of `<Commentable,Long>` then?